# Fiddler not capturing http request from java code running on jrockit

Tags: http, fiddler, jrockit

I have my application running on jrockit jvm and I have set the jvm parameters as -DproxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost= -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888.

But I dont see the http traffic routed though fiddler when a java application is making http calls. Looks like proxyHost/ProxyPort is not working in jrockit.

Thanks.